# SendKeys Not Capturing all Data

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, sendkeys

I'm using VBA code to take data from excel and populate a pdf from using SendKeys.
This works for 99% of all of my data, but I'm noticing in some instances, the data from excel is not fully transferring to the PDF.

For example, in cell D3, I have the text "17.04% / 17.84%" (note- this is a text field, so minus the quotes, this is exactly how the text is formatted).

When I run this code:

```
Application.SendKeys Sheet10.Range("D3").Value, True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
```

The result is "17.04", leaving the percentage signs and the other half of the text.

I know that sendkeys is known to be problematic, so is there an alternative way of transferring excel data to pdf?

If not, is there a way to have the sendkeys capture the full text? I tried adding the "Application.Wait Now + 0.00001" but this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Would you be helped reading [this](http://myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/read-and-write-pdf-forms-from-excel-vba.html) post so you can avoid `SendKeys`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape characters which have special significance to SendKeys, such as `%`

Try this:

```
v = Sheet10.Range("D3").Value

Application.SendKeys Replace(v,"%","{%}"), True
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses ( ) have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use {+}.